# subprocess.Popen ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run a python script through another python script, with subprocess.Popen. I have:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3',
                  'myscript.py'])
p.poll() is None
```

Sometimes I get:

```
Out[21]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x11b5823a0>
```

But nothing happens and the script is not executed.
Some other times I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 11, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I am pretty sure that the requests module have been properly imported in the script I am trying to run. Any help welcome ;)

Comment: ``Out[21]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x11b5823a0>`` suggests you are running this through ipython or similar, not directly as a script. Likewise, sometimes getting missing modules suggests you run this via an unexpected python version. Does anything of your setup dynamically select the python interpreter?

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi it might be Spyder that selects it for me? Or spyder that uses a distinct python interpreter than the one in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3'?

Comment: So how to solve this problem ? I face same problem: run python code in subprocess, it will show "No module named rarfile". it seem to create new env for subprocess ~